# Magento2 : How to restrict new categories assignment while importing products via CSV

Tags: magento2, category, import

When I import product from CSV file with new categories then magento2 create new categories.

But magento assign these categories to all stores, I want to restrict this and want that these categories will be enabled only on default store.

How can I achieve this?
Should I add any event in custom module which disabled back these categories to sub store views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this, I don't know it is a proper way or not but for now it is working for me. If anyone has best/standard solution then please post.

Here is my solution : (this is also working when a new category is added from admin panel)

In events.xml added two events :

```
...
<event name="catalog_category_save_before">
    <observer name="custome_categorysavebefore" instance="Company\Custom\Model\CategorySaveBefore" shared="false" />
</event>
<event name="catalog_category_save_after">
    <observer name="custome_categorysaveafter" instance="Company\Custom\Model\CategorySaveAfter" shared="false" />
</event>
...
```

In `CategorySaveBefore.php` :

```
...
$this->category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
if (!$this->category->getId()) 
{
    // set in session to use in after event
    $logger->info('new');
} 
...
```

In `CategorySaveAfter.php` :

```
...
// $is_new -> check from session
if($is_new == 1 && ($store_id == 0 || $store_id == 1))
{
    $stores =  $this->storeManager->getStores($withDefault = false);
    foreach($stores  as $eachStoreId => $val)
    {
        if($eachStoreId == 0 || $eachStoreId == 1)
            continue;
        $category_obj = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($this->category->getId());
        $category_obj->setStoreId($eachStoreId);
        $category_obj->setData('is_active', 0);
        $category_obj->save();
    }
}
// unset session varaible
...
```